# Targeting a higher version of a pre-loaded Nuget package in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

I'm writing an Azure function which uses `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` to check the status of rehydrating blobs when they move from Archive to Cold.

To do this, I need to check the `StandardBlobTier` field of the blob properties. I believe this is a fairly new property in the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` nuget package and so I need to target the latest version.

I target version 9.1.0 in my project.json but I still get the error: `'BlobProperties' does not contain a definition for 'StandardBlobTier'`. What version of `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` is automatically being loaded to Azure Functions environment and how do I override it?

Source code:

```
#r "System.IO"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Dapper;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol;

public static async Task Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{    

    var archiveStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("{storageConnectionString}");

    CloudBlobClient blobClient = archiveStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    // Retrieve a reference to a container. 
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

    // Retrieve reference to a blob.
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

    try
    {
        //Fill blob properties
        await blockBlob.FetchAttributesAsync();

        if (blockBlob.Properties.StandardBlobTier.HasValue && blockBlob.Properties.StandardBlobTier.Value == StandardBlobTier.Cool)
        {
            //Blob ready
        }

        //Blob still rehydrating
    }
    catch (StorageException ex) { throw; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the latest version of Windows.Azure.Storage os 9.1.1: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/9.1.1

I also looked up the documentation, and it looks like `StandardBlobTier` is part of the nameSpace: **`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob`** , Could you try using this name space instead of `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` ?

More documentation on StandardBlobTier: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.standardblobtier?view=azure-dotnet

**Update:**
Azure Functions uses Storage SDK version 7.2.1.0 which doesn’t have the new property, however, the internal devs confirmed  that it was possible to call the latest version of the storage SDK by creating a customer project.json and call the latest version:

```
  Project.json:
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage": "9.0.0"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

In this case, you may need to remove ‘#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"’

Comment: Yes, it's part of the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob` namespace, but it still belongs to the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` nuget package.
I'm using that namespace but obviously the version that is pre-loaded doesn't contain the `StandardBlobTier` property.

Comment: Let me check with some of the internal teams and i'll get back to you.

Comment: Could you add the code you're using in your question ?

Comment: Added function source code to the question, thanks for taking a look!

Comment: I just got feedback from the internal team,I added the updated portion in the answer to target the community that maybe having the same issue.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, Adam. I'm sure I did try this in the past but when I'm back at my machine I'll try this and update with how I get on.